# How to change category for Panels IPE

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

How would I change the category from "Fielded panes" in Panels IPE to something else?

I can accomplish this through the following code:

```
function template_preprocess_panels_add_content_modal(&$vars) {
  $i = 0;
  foreach($vars['categories_array'] as $item) {
    $new_item = str_replace("Fielded panes", "New Content", $item);
    $vars['categories_array'][$i] = $new_item;
    $i++;
  }
}
```

However, I'd like to find a more elegant solution by altering the category name in a function that runs before **template_preprocess_panels_add_content_modal()**.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [template_preprocess_panels_add_content_modal](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/template_preprocess_panels_add_content_modal/7)() and `$vars['categories']`. You should be able to override the category names there.

**Edit:**

Ahh, yes, I forgot about [hook_ctools_content_subtype_alter()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!ctools.api.php/function/hook_ctools_content_subtype_alter/7). That's more elegant :)

From the documentation:

> This hook can be used to add things like 'render last' or change icons
>   or categories or to rename content on specific sites.

In the example below the category "Fielded panes" is changed to "New category name".

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_content_subtype_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_ctools_content_subtype_alter(&$subtype, &$plugin) {
  if ($subtype['category'] == 'Fielded panes') {
    $subtype['category'] = 'New category name';
  }
}
```

Comment: By the time that function runs, $vars['categories_array'] has already been built, and so overriding $vars['categories'] doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I discovered that this can easily be accomplished via hook_ctools_content_subtype_alter().

```
  /**
  * Implements hook_ctools_content_subtype_alter().
  */
  function MYMODULE_ctools_content_subtype_alter(&$subtype, &$plugin) {
    if ($subtype['category'] == 'Fielded panes') {
      $subtype['category'] = 'New category name';
    }
  }
```

I also discovered that I can alter the title and the icon by doing something like this:

```
/**
* Implements hook_ctools_content_subtype_alter().
*/
function MYMODULE_ctools_content_subtype_alter(&$subtype, &$plugin) {
  // Change title and icon for rich_text Fielded panel pane content
  if (isset($subtype['bundle']) && $subtype['bundle'] == 'rich_text') {
    $subtype['title'] = 'Custom Content';
    $subtype['path'] = 'sites/default/files/ctools/icons';
    $subtype['icon'] = 'content.png';
  }
}
```